# MFC and UI Automation Support

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, automation

First, I am very new to Microsoft programming in general.

The situation
I have a MFC application that has a dockable toolbar with various buttons such as "New File", "Save File" and so forth. Essentially, what I need to achieve is a way to automate clicking these buttons. From using various GUI spying tools such as UISpy and Visual UI Automation, I am able to see the toolbar object with a AutomationID, ClassName and so forth. However, I am unable to see the children buttons of this toolbar. Anyway to expose these objects? here is a screenshot http://postimg.org/image/n2drpxaa3/

I have access to source code if I need to change something there.

Answer (score 2):

The toolbar buttons are not true button controls, they are just painted there by the toolbar. To simulate clicking those buttons send a WM_COMMAND message to the main window. You can use a Spy program to determine the parameters needed to duplicate the message sent by the toolbar button.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Learn something new. So just to make sure I fully understand, I am able to spy out that when I click a button on my toolbar, in Winspector, I see that a WM_COMMAND is sent. It has the fields (Code: 0 Control ID: 57601 Control HWND:0x0000000). In C#, I basically do SendMessage(hwnd, 57601, IntPtr.Zero, IntPrt.Zero) and then I have basically just simulated clicking a toolbar button on my UI?

Comment: I am having a problem with getting this to work though. Should the WM_COMMAND equal 0x111 and the wParam be 57601?

Comment: Your should be able to use ::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, 57601, 0); without looking up hex values for Windows messages. Also, you should be able to confirm the 57601 ID by looking in the resource.h file of the target program.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Just another followup question. I have a "button" on my toolbar that when clicked, pops up a context/popup menu with some options. I tried spying to see if there was a wm_command being sent when this action occurs but did not find one. I did manage to find the following after left clicking. <00042> 00080960 R WM_ACTIVATE
<00043> 00080960 S WM_SETMESSAGESTRING wStringID:0000AC5A lpszString:00000000
<00044> 00080960 R WM_SETMESSAGESTRING
<00045> 00080960 S WM_INITMENUPOPUP hmenuPopup:07520C79 uPos:0 fSystemMenu:False
<00046> 00080960 R WM_INITMENUPOPUP